# Opening Linux Console from C code

Tags: c, linux, shell, linux-kernel, console

I'm trying to learn and understand Linux using my x86-64 desktop. I'm multibooting Linux using OpenSuse 13.1 as my working system. I've created a learning system on its own partition with just 2 files. I've compiled a 3.16.2 Kernel with default options its in /boot. The following file init:

```
int main() {
  int nbytes = 100;
  char * str;    
  str = (char *) malloc(nbytes + 1);
  puts ("Please Enter text");
  while (1) {
    getline(&str, &nbytes, stdin);       
    puts(str);
    puts("line recieved");
    if (str[0] == 'r')
     reboot(0x1234567);
    if (str[0] == 's')
          reboot(0x4321fedc);        
  }
  return 0;
}
```

is statically compiled and is in /sbin. Init is a very primitive shell, but it would be a chore to develop it further in C code. Wikipedia says:

"The Linux console is a system console internal to the Linux kernel"

So if this is really in the Kernel can I call this console from my init programme without having to add in any other dependencies / files / programmes? If so how? Do I need to to rebuild the Kernel with specific options? If not how can I get a console / terminal / CLI shell up with the absolute minimum of files so that I can easily call basic system commands?

Note I've installed Arch a number of times, but both Arch and Linux From Scratch have hundreds if not thousands of files in their most basic systems. Also I'm trying to understand Linux in general and embedded Linux and Android could use totally different extras, so I'm trying a different learning approach.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the difference between a `console` and a `shell`. RE: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con

Answer (score 0):

Trying using fork() and exec() to launch the bash program.

```
fork();
exec("path/to/bash");
```

You could even do something like exec("bash myscript.sh");

EDIT: You may need to choose one of the exec family functions